# How to make my next sampler in Jmeter wait till my file gets downloaded?

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where I have two samplers inside a thread group.In one sampler I perform a POST request which triggers file download process.The process will continue till all the details of the files are fetched completely in backend.Then in the next sampler,I perform a GET request and I get the downloaded file link in Response.Using that link i can download the file from server.

When I run the thread group,the second sampler gets executed even in middle of my file download process and i get the empty data in Response even though the response code of second sampler is 200.

So i need to make the second sampler wait till my file download request fetches all details of the file.

Comment: How to identify if the process is completed in the backend? You could query the backend and wait till the process is completed with a while controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. You can put some form of "hard wait" using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler or suitable [JMeter Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/) so the next "GET" request will always be executed in i.e. 5 minutes after the POST request
2. If there is a way to verify the progress of the "background process" using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) or [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler you can put it under a [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and wait for the process completion.